# What are the possible reasons for this application [ Application number US 13/653,469 ] to be rejected under US Patent Laws?

Tags: patentability, us20130128027

```
Publication number  US20130128027 A1
Publication type    Application
Application number  US 13/653,469
Publication date    May 23, 2013
Filing date         Oct 17, 2012
Priority date       Nov 18, 2011
Also published as   CN103124358A, EP2595375A1
Inventors           Masaaki Katsurada, Keisuke Nagoshi
Original Assignee   Keyence Corporation
Export Citation     BiBTeX, EndNote, RefMan
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. Are you looking for the sections of law that all patents need to satisfy to be allowed or an analysis, search and examination of this application or something else?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I'm looking for the second part of your question that's an analysis or research or an examination that explains that this application is not patentable because of which other prior inventions and how those already disclose or teach the claims of this application.

Answer (score 0):

This task would be very similar to validity search suplimented with an analysis by a patent practitioner or to the comprehensive search and report required for accelerated examination. I would guess the validity search + analysis would be $3,000 or more and the accelerated examination search and report (without all the formalities required by the USPTO) might be about $5,000.

You didn't mention your overall goal but it could be thwarted by ignoring the applicant's ability to amend and create a moving target.

Comment: I'm just looking for a generalized analysis not too elaborated or emphasized one.

Comment: You can reframe the question using the ask patents template for requesting help locating prior art. As the question is written it sounds like you are asking someone to talk to take on a significant project.